# dataTable: при ajax.reload() теряется важный параметр (не инициализируется)

Tags: jquery, datatable, html-form

У меня есть datatable `var table = $('#example').dataTable()`, которая наполняется при выборе элемента в выпадающем списке (dropdown). ТО есть я хочу в выпадающем списке выбирать элемент и это действие инициирует AJAX-запрос в котором используется значение `.val()` выбранного элемента.

На странице есть также элемент `<select>`, который во время дизайна пуст и он наполняется другим AJAX-запросом. Так же есть элемент `<input type="hidden">` который хранит значение выбранного элемента и потом постит его в форме:

```
<div>
  <select class="form-control" id="objs" style="display:none">
  </select>
</div>

<input class="form-control" type="hidden" id="oid" name="oid" value="0">
```

Вот так я пытаюсь реализовать свою задачу:

```
$('#objs').change(function() {
  $('input[name="oid"]').val(this.value);
  table.DataTable({
    ajax: {
      data: {oid: $('#oid').val()}
    }
  });
  //alert($('input[name="oid"]').val());
  table.DataTable().ajax.reload();
});
```

Событие `onChange` выпадающего списка отрабатывает прекрасно и я в alert'е даже виду значение элемента! То есть мне удается программно присвоить значение элементу `<input>`. Но затем, когда я вызываю `DataTable().ajax.reload()` это значение куда-то теряется. То есть в форме оно может и передаётся, но принимающий контроллер говорит, что его нет. Оно попросту неинициализированно:

```
Array
(
  [oid] => 
)
```

Что я делаю не так? Есть ощущение, что может быть проблема с областью видимости переменных или же dataTable как-то подменяет значения формы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Увы, но за минувшую неделю мой вопрос просмотрели всего 9-ть раз и я решил поискать счастья на англоговорящем Stackoverflow. В итоге я получил [прекрасный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55077246/during-datatable-ajax-request-a-hidden-form-control-never-gets-initialized/55095832#55095832), содержащий весьма изящный способ решения моей задачи. Дело в том, что в момент инициализации DataTable параметр `oid` инициализируется ***текущим*** значением `$('#oid').val()`. А для того, чтобы динамически получать этот параметр и передавать его в ajax-запрос, следует использовать функцию:

```
table.DataTable({
  ajax: {
    data: function ( d ) {
      d.oid = $('#oid').val();
    }
  }
});
```